# How to keep background in fixed place while scrolling

Tags: html, css, background-image

Here is the css

```
#bigwrapper{
    background-image: url('http://www.w8themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Water-Backgrounds.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<body id="bigwrapper">...</body>
```

As i scroll down i want to be able to keep the background image in the same place. I did this with my header and it worked, but hasn't worked out for the background image. Here is how i did it with my header

css below

```
.header1{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -100px auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    background: rgba(107, 168, 237, .8);
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

html below

```
<div id="title" class="header1">
        <header><h1 ="title1" class="allTitle">The Water Project</h1></header>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a DIV inside BODY and set styling for DIV

Comment: See my answer. no need to use DIV.

Comment: @user3612995 : see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4K89a/

Answer (score 6):

Use this style:

```
#bigwrapper {
    background-image: url('http://www.w8themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Water-Backgrounds.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You have to use `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Answer (score 2):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wunid/1/edit)**

```
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

The above line will make the background image fixed.

```
#bigwrapper{
        background-image: url('http://www.w8themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Water-Backgrounds.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: top left;
         background-attachment: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was creating a fiddle, got sidetracked for a bit before posting, and it looks like others beat me to the punch.  Just for the sake of doing something with what I worked on, here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/867VX/3/embedded/result/

And like the others said, use

```
background-attachment: fixed
```