# CSS Background Image overlay

Tags: css

I was wondering. How do I make it to where when you scroll down the page on a website, the background kind of follows it. Example here, https://alexcican.com/post/455k-users/ . I want something like the very top of the page to happen, can anyone point me in the right directional?s

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep background in fixed place while scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570727/how-to-keep-background-in-fixed-place-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Become familiar with positions (relative, absolute, and fixed). That is the main element, however, that also triggers other properties you need to be aware of. For instance, you lose the width and height when you do any hard positioning such as fixed. So, the items below must correct for that height. In order to properly do this without any glitches, consider the margin-top to 100% on the content. That will compensate for the hard positioning.  Other things you should consider playing with when dealing with hard positioning are your z-indexes. As fixed positioning will natively position the element on top of your document. In order for it to hide, you should bring it down a layer or two (as necessary).

Do the following:

```
<div class="wrapper-parallax">
  <div class="parallax">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>

  <section class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background: url(http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4238051-background.jpg) center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    background: #ededed;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-parallax {
    margin-top: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 150px;
    color: #9A1414;
}

.content h1 {
    line-height: 500px;
    color: #999;
}
```

See it working [**here**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qbGJVz)

Comment: Thank's @LOTUSMS, This works fine. Now, with this. I saw on Alex Cican's blog details page, he has a font-awesome icon or maybe bootstrap icon (I can't tell right off the bat), how does he replace the picture with the icon?

Comment: Go to font awesome and download the css library file and include it in your site. Then use this in place of the image `<i class="fa fa-anyicon"></i>`. You can find the name of the icon if you click on icons in the font awesome website and click the icon you want. You should see exactly the code I just wrote